# Solve PSD linear system

Tags: cython, lapack, blas

I am trying to compute with BLAS/LAPACK the matrix $A - A B^{-1} A$ where A is symmetric and B is PSD.
What would be the smartest way to do this?
I was thinking to compute a Cholesky decomposition $B = LL^T$ and then solve $L^T X = A$.
But how to do this last step? Is it possible to exploit the fact that $A$ is symmetric?

I am using Cython and the provided BLAS/LAPACK interface (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.cython_blas.html).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please mention the language you're doing this in, or which ones you would accept an answer with for this question (there are many implementations and interfaces for BLAS/LAPACK).

Comment: Thanks for the comment; I edited my question. (I am using Cython.)

Comment: Is B symmetric positive definit (spd) or positive semi-definit (psd)? psd doesnt imply invertible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A is symmetric `A^T=A` and B is symmetric positive definit.

Find the Cholesky decomposition of `B=LL^T` by [LAPACK `?potrf`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/lapack-routines/lapack-linear-equation-routines/lapack-linear-equation-computational-routines/matrix-factorization-lapack-computational-routines/potrf.html).
This will save `L` into `B` as a lower triangular matrix (note to set the first argument `uplo='L'` in `?potrf`).

As a next step you can solve `LX=A` for `X` by using [LAPACK `?trtrs`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/lapack-routines/lapack-linear-equation-routines/lapack-linear-equation-computational-routines/solving-systems-of-linear-equations-lapack-computational-routines/trtrs.html).
Make sure to set `uplo='L'` again.

Using the following computation

```latex
A B^{-1} A 
= A (LL^T)^{-1} A 
= A L^{-T} L^{-1} A 
= (L^{-1} A)^T L^{-1} A 
= X^T X
```

it is clear that you only need to multiply `X^T X`.
That can be done by [BLAS `?syrk`](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/onemkl-developer-reference-fortran/top/blas-and-sparse-blas-routines/blas-routines/blas-level-3-routines/syrk.html).
The following code computes `ABinvA := X^T X`

```
call syrk(X, ABinvA, trans='T')
```

The final result is a simple subtraction operation

```py
res = A - ABinvA
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you think of 'dsyrk' instead of 'gemm' to compute the product X^T X?

Comment: You are correct. It might be more efficient. I'll update my answer.